# Why does Foundation recommend adding a tabindex="0" to main content?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

In [Foundation's docs on creating skip links](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html#creating-skip-links), they recommend adding `tabindex="0"` to the element that represents the main content to skip to. I'm a bit confused as to why they would say that. As far as I can see, this results in an extra element receiving focus when tabbing through the document, even though there's not really anything to do with that element focused.

Is the reason perhaps compatibility with older browsers that don't support anchoring to `id`s? Or is there another reason?

**Update:** It should soon no longer say the above anymore, but that's because [I changed it](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/10347) in response to the answers here :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `tabindex` to the -1 value in order for the element to be programmatically focusable but not to be included in the tab order (in opposite to the 0 value).

If your anchor targets an unfocusable element then, the window will scroll to this element but a next press on the `tab` key will focus the next element after the skip link button.

See for instance the [definition of focusable](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focusable) according to the W3C:

> The element's tabindex focus flag is set.

Comment: Hmm, `tabindex="-1"` does sound more logical. It appears that at least Firefox and Chrome still focus the element without it, but after browsing through the spec, I think that's not required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be for the simple reason as to quickly be able to navigate to the most important section of the page. This element will be selected first when pressing `tab` and the selection will continue from there rather than at the top of the DOM.

Using anchoring `id`s is for use when the user clicks an internal link or needs otherwise to be triggered though JS. Using `tabindex="0"` is already built into most browsers.

Comment: Do you mean that if I follow the skip link, without adding `tabindex="0"`, pressing `tab` would put me at the first focusable element after the skip link? Because that's not the behaviour I'm observing: if I follow the link, then press `tab`, the first element in the main content area gets focused.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted the question. You are correct although I do believe that the element skipped to doesn't get the `tab` priority in all/old browsers.

Comment: Yeah I guess that must be the reason. Setting it to `-1` appears to be the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the main content is given an `id` which a skip link uses to jump the user's focus to the main content. However, this straight forward approach [doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/01/15/fixing-skip-to-content-links/). You need to set the focus to the main content using javascript `focus()`. And `tabindex=0` is used to make an element that is not inherently capable of receiving focus, focusable.